# Input a string into an unsigned short array in C++

Tags: c++

I have to input a string into an unsigned short array.

Here is my implementation:

```
unsigned short strFile [ 200 ] = {0};
cin >> strFile;
```

I have included the `iostream.h` header.

But I always get an error:

> error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream'

Anybody knows how should I solve this?

Comment: Any specific reason for not using `std::string`?

Comment: isn't std::wstring basically an unsigned short array? Like `std::wstring x; std::getline(std::wcin, x);` ?

Comment: @stijn: No, `std::wstring` is `wchar_t` array. `wchar_t` is required to be distinct type by C++ standard. In C it may be typedef to `unsigned short`, but in C++ it may not.

Comment: What the hell is a un array?  Oh, I'll just fix it...

Comment: `#include <iostream.h>` hasn't been correct for over 14 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no kind of string that would be compatible with `unsigned short[]`.

There is normal string that is `char []` (in C++ you should always keep it in `string` except for constants!) and wide string, that is `wchar_t[]` (in C++ you should always keep it in `wstring`). And C++11 adds `char16_t` and `char32_t` and their corresponding `u16string` and `u32string`.

You can read normal string from normal input stream like `cin`. You can read wide string from *wide* input stream like `wcin`.

`wchar_t` used to be typedef to `unsigned short` in C, but C++ requires it to be a separate type. ISO/IEC
14882:2003 3.9.1/5:

> Type `wchar_t` is a distinct type whose values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales (22.1.1).

Comment: `unsigned short*` is still used in WinAPI, e.g. in the `SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY` structure.

Comment: `unsigned short*` is still used by Pdfium today to extract text from PDF documents (see [FDPF_GetText](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/refs/heads/main/public/fpdf_text.h))

I feel the initial suggestion that "there is no kind of string that would be compatible with unsigned short[]" is a bit disingenuous. You even state in your last sentence that `wchar_t` used to be typedef to `unsigned short`.

In fact, `unsigned short` is wide enough to accommodate both `char` and `wchar_t` and each element in `unsigned short[]` can be assigned to a character in a `string` or `wstring`

Comment: @djrecipe `unsigned short` is only wide enough to accommodate `wchar_t` on Windows, where `wchar_t` got stuck on 2 bytes. Other platforms followed the specification I quoted above and extended their `wchar_t` to 4 bytes, which then does not fit in `unsigned short`. Yes, `unsigned short` is used in lot of places for explicitly storing UTF-16, but that's not a string as far as the C++ compiler or it's accompanying standard library are concerned (well, you can teach standard library how to treat it as string, by defining appropriate char_traits, but you have to do it yourself).

Comment: @JanHudec good point. If I understand correctly, reading from `unsigned short[]` into `wchar_t[]` should work on all platforms (as is necessary in my case with FPDF_GetText which must use UTF-16), but you cannot safely store `wchar_t[]` into `unsigned short[]` on all platforms without truncating 2 bytes on Unix platforms.

Platform-independent character encoding is such a headache..